# How to add multiple event (mouseover/mouseout) into one selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I `mouseover`/`mouseout` very fast  more than one time during animation times (here 900). Button  is animating more than one time; even when I stopped mouse activity.

I want that it will take only one event for animation during animation times; even when multiple event triggered.
Other way I want to say if I triggered multiple `mouseover` event  during 900 it will terminate immediately when I triggered `mouseout` and vice-versa.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css({
            background: 'transparent',
            color: '#09F'
        });
        $("button").animate({
            width: "110%",
        }, 900);
        $(this).text("Show More >");
    });
    $("button").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css({
            background: '#09F',
            color: '#FFF'
        });
        $("button").animate({
            width: "100%",
        }, 900);
        $(this).text("Show More");
    });
});
```

[Here's an JSFiddle to show you the behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/goldfingerxyz/Y26zS/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/goldfingerxyz/Y26zS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**`.stop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css({
            background: 'transparent',
            color: '#09F'
        });
        $("button").stop().animate({ //Here used stop
            width: "110%",
        }, 900);
        $(this).text("Show More >");
    });
    $("button").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css({
            background: '#09F',
            color: '#FFF'
        });
        $("button").stop().animate({ //Here used stop
            width: "100%",
        }, 900);
        $(this).text("Show More");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypkd8/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes every time because you have some duration for example

```
$('somelemenent').animate({}, 400);
```

Your animation will stay in order if you hover element more quickly than your duration. 
For this cases, you should set:

```
$('somelement').stop().animate(/* and your properties */);
```

Method .stop() stops all effects and orders which have connection with current element.

Answer (score 1):

Use this : add another event after finishing previous one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").mouseover(function() {
          $( this ).css({background :'transparent',color : '#09F'}); 
          $( "button").stop().animate({width: "110%",}, 900 ); 
          $(this).text("Show More >"); 
       }).mouseout(function() { 
           $( this ).css({background :'#09F',color : '#FFF'}); 
           $( "button").stop().animate({width: "100%",}, 900 );
           $(this).text("Show More"); 
       });

});
```

Comment: ok. I got the idea of single selector here. But still I got the bouncing effect If I mouseover and mouseout on that button multiple times [fast].

Comment: The code is similar to OPs code apart from chaining.

Comment: @Satpal, yes you are right. updated my answer to stop animation before start